# "Course" vs. "class"

Tags: word-choice

I was wondering if someone could tell me if using the word "course" instead of "class" in the sentences below makes sense and if "course" sounds natural or not:

> - We used to always skip math class in school.
> - I go to a language class on Thursdays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both of these sentences, the meaning of [class](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/class) is **a period of time in which students are taught something**.

[Course](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/course) has only one meaning: **a set of classes or a plan of study on a particular subject, usually leading to an exam or qualification**.

> We used to always skip math class in school

You can skip classes but saying that you *always* skipped math courses would sound like you managed to skip every class for every year.

> I go to a language class on Thursdays

Each individual class is on a Thursday, but the course involves a number of classes and lasts a certain period of time, for example a year. It doesn't sound right to say that the course is on a Thursday. You could however say

> I am doing a language course and the classes are on Thursdays.